# What are some classic examples of feature selection in classification?

Tags: classification, data-visualization, feature-selection

Is there a classic example showing the importance of good feature selection in classification?  The ideal example would be simple, and very easy to understand.

I've been volunteered/instructed to put together a short presentation for work to explain some basics of classification techniques.  Many members of my audience have never done classification before, so I'd like to keep the example as simple as possible while still using real data.  Even if you can't point me to a data-set, if you could provide a example idea, I would greatly appreciate it.

The best idea I've been able to come up with so far, is a really old vending machine that needs to sort out which coins are real and which ones are fake.